# How to place a static button in the bottom rigth corner?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to place a button in the bottom right corner of the page and make it static. It needs to keep in its place in case of scroll.

I have tried to place it vía css but i don't have enough level.

```
<input type="button" onclick="delegar.php" id="delegar" value="Delegar">

#delegar {
    position:relative;
    rigth: 100%;
    bottom: 100%;
}
```

Comment: add your CSS Code Here.

Comment: @LaljiTadhani done

Comment: You can fix it using  position: fixed and also fix using position: absolute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your CSS

```
#delegar {
    position:fixed;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use position fixed to do such task.It will keep your button at bottom .

```
#delegar {
    position:fixed;
    rigth: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container-bottom">
    <input type="button" onclick="delegar.php" id="delegar" value="Delegar">
</div>

.container-bottom { position: relative; }

#delegar {
    position:relative;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the position of element to fixed. see example below:

```
.fixed {
position: fixed;
bottom: 10px;
right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Now you can set this class 'fixed' to any element you want to fix. Like:
<input type="button" onclick="delegar.php" id="delegar" class="fixed" value="Delegar">